# How can I sort using ant design's table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am developing a react project using ant design. I want to use the sorter properties in the table. For example, I want to re-request asc or desc for the name in the table according to the value returned from the table, I want to project it to the api table. How do I do this? I need help.

```
  const fetchData = async () => {
setloading(true);
const { current, pageSize } = tableParams.pagination;
const postModel = {
  PageIndex: current,
  PageSize: pageSize,
  Filter: '',
  OrderDir: 'ASC',
  OrderField: 'Id',
};
const response = await ticketService.getList(postModel);
setData(response.datas);
setloading(false);
setTableParams({
  ...tableParams,
  pagination: {
    ...tableParams.pagination,
    total: response.totalItemsCount,
  }
})
};

const handleTableChange = (pagination, filters, sorter) => {
  setTableParams({
    pagination,
    filters,
    ...sorter,
  });
  if (pagination.pageSize !== tableParams.pagination?.pageSize) {
    setData([]);
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchData();
  document.title = 'Ticket List';
}, [JSON.stringify(tableParams)]);
 const myColumns = [
{
  title: <SyncOutlined />,
  render: (record) => (
    <>
      <Space.Compact>
      <Button shape="circle" icon={<SearchOutlined />} href={`/ticket/action/list/${record.id}`}/>
      <Button danger shape="circle" icon={<DeleteOutlined />} onClick={() => handleDelete(record.id)}/>
      </Space.Compact>
    </>
  ),
  width: '10%',
  responsive: ['md'],
},
{
  title: 'User Name',
  dataIndex: 'createUserName',
  key:'createUserName',
  sorter:true,
  render: (createUserName) => `${createUserName}`,
  responsive: ['md'],
  width: '30%',
},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data type use these functions

`String`:

```js
 sorter: (a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name)
```

`Number`:

```js
sorter: (a, b) => a.number - b.number
```

`Boolean`

```js
sorter: (a, b) => a.value - b.value
// happens due to coercion
```

Comment: Yes, this solves my problem, but if I do the solution by sending a request to the api again, I think it will be more logical and better, how can I do it that way? Is not it?